# highlighting current menu problems

Tags: jquery, css, menu, highlight

I'm not understanding why I'm not able to highlight the current menu page on a navigation bar (except the fact I'm a total beginner :-)
I'm using a JQuery function, one among many I've found on the net, none of them working.
Function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var path=window.location.pathname;
        path=path.replace(/\/$/, "");
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);

        $('#menu a').each(function() {
            var href=$(this).attr('href');
            if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }

        });

        });
    </script>
```

My Css is:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#menu{ width:100%; height:40px; background-color: pink; border-bottom: 1px silver solid;}

#menu ul {

    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto; 
    position: relative;
    padding:5px 0;
    width: 940px;
}

#menu ul li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 150px;

          }

#menu li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
    }         

#menu ul li a {
  color: silver;
  display:block-inline;
  font: 16px "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;  
        }


#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.active{
    color:green;
    }
```

The HTML markup is:

```
<?php
echo<<<END

    <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a id="home" style="color:white; font-size:16px;" href="$doc_root/index.php" title="Home Page">Enzo</a></li>
                    <li><a id="travel" href="$doc_root/travel/grid.php" title="My Trips"><span>travelling</span></a></li>
                    <li><a id="images" href="#">images</a></li>
                    <li><a id="words" href="#">words</a></li>
                    <li><a id="about" href="#">about</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>  
END;
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong, probably my css.
For the sake of simplicity is just color:green, I'm not sure the "active" class is correctly inserted into CSS menu page.
Pls give me some hints or some other solution to solve the problem.
Love u All
:-)

Comment: and let me add the html markup:

Comment: here href="$doc_root/index.php", you have to add href="<?php echo $doc_root; ?>/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the $doc_root which I presume is a PHP variable is in the format

```
<?=$doc_root?>
```

alternatively if you do not have short open PHP tags turned on try

```
<?php echo $doc_root; ?>
```

instead.

This is to make sure that it gets written out in the html correctly. If you view the source of your work in the browser and you can see $doc_root and not the value of variable $doc_root then thats probably where the issue is.

Comment: No Guys, that part is already included into php tags, which are not shown in the HTML part I've attached

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes in your code

[image]

**Javascript modified**

```
 $(function () {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
            path = decodeURIComponent(path);

            $('#menu a').each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (href.indexOf(path) != -1) {
                    $(this).closest('li').find('a').addClass('active');
                }

            });

        });
```

**Modified CSS**

```
#menu ul li a {    
  display:block-inline;
  font: 16px "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;  
        }
```

**HTML Modified**

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="home" href="http://localhost:50160/SelectedMenu.aspx" title="Home Page">Enzo</a></li>
                <li><a id="travel" href="#" title="My Trips"><span>travelling</span></a></li>
                <li><a id="images" href="#">images</a></li>
                <li><a id="words" href="#">words</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="#">about</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: no way Chirag, I applied your changes,  it's like .active class is not having any effect on the menu item !!!

Comment: Can you please provide your current code? After you applied my changes, as I already supplied you screenshot showing output expected by you.

Comment: Chirag, it was jquery library issue. With local library did not work, using google api it is...strange indeed. Thks a lot for yuor interest anyway.